# Who will do the Auto-boxing/unboxing?

Tags: java, autoboxing

Is it the compiler or the runtime do the auto-boxing/unboxing?

Consider the following example:

```
public Integer get() {
    return 1;  //(1)
}
```

At (1), the primitive integer value will be converted into something like `new Integer(1)`, and returned. That's effectively some kind of implict consverion known as auto-boxing , but who will do that? The compiler, or the JVM?

I was just starting to learn the ASM, and such boxing issue really confuse me.

Comment: consider this:
int a = myScan.nextInt();
Integer b = a;
how will the compiler do this, without being able to know what value a will have?

Comment: @Stultuske The compiler will to `Integer b = Integer.valueOf(a);`. Simple. It doesn't need to know the value of `a`. See also the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see the disassembled code using the [`javap -c`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) command:

```
public class Example {
  public Example();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1    // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public java.lang.Integer get();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: invokestatic  #2   // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       4: areturn
}
```

You can see that the `Integer#valueOf` was invoked, so the actual code gets translated to:

```
public Integer get(){
    return Integer.valueOf(1);
}
```

---

Conclusion:

The compiler does it for you.